# TypeError: this.props.mutate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm trying to add a user with this.props.mutate, however im getting this error

```
TypeError: this.props.mutate is not a function
```

I have the resolvers set up in such a way that createUser can be called. However, im not sure what am i doing wrong.

What should i do to make react call the apollo mutation createUser ?

thanks in advance

**server/resolvers.js**

```
export default {
    User: {
      posts: (parent, args, context, info) => parent.getPosts()
    },
    Post: {
      user: (parent, args, context, info) => parent.getUser()
    },
    Query: {
      posts: (parent, args, { db }, info) => db.Post.findAll(),
      users: (parent, args, { db }, info) => db.User.findAll(),
      post: (parent, { id }, { db }, info) => db.Post.findByPk(id),
      user: (parent, { id }, { db }, info) => db.User.findByPk(id)
    },
    Mutation: {
      createUser:(parent, {username, email, password}, {db} , info) => 
        db.User.create({
          username: username, 
          email: email,
          password: password
        })

    }

  };
```

**server/schema.js**

```
export default `
  type User {
    id: Int!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    posts: [Post!]!
  }
  type Post {
    id: Int!
    title: String
    content: String!
    userId: Int!
    user: User!
  }
  type Query {
    posts: [Post!]!
    post(id: Int!): Post
    user(id: Int!): User
    users: [User!]!
  }
  type Mutation {
    createPost(title: String, content:String!): Post!
    createUser(username: String!, email: String!, password: String!): User!

  }
`;
```

**client side resolvers**

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';
const getUsersQuery = gql`
{
    users {
      id
      username
      email
      password
  }
}
`;

const createUserQuery = gql`
  mutation createUser($username: String!, $password: String!, $email: String!) {
    createUser(username: $username, password: $password, email:$email) {
      id
      username
      email
      password
    }
  }
`;


export {
  getUsersQuery,
  createUserQuery
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";
import './App.css';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import { getUsersQuery,createUserQuery} from './queries/queries'
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      username: '',
      password: '',
      email: ''
    }
  }
  handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
  addUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.mutate({ 
      variables: { 
        username: this.state.username, 
        password: this.state.password,
        email:this.state.email
      }
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.data.users !== this.props.data.users){
      this.setState({
        users: this.props.data.users
      })
    }
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        owl
          <form onSubmit ={this.addUser}>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type ="text" name="username" value ={this.state.username} placeholder="Enter Username"/>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type ="text" name="password" value ={this.state.password} placeholder="Enter Password"/>
            <input onChange={this.handleChange} type ="text" name="email" value ={this.state.email} placeholder="Enter Email"/>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
          {this.state.users.map( (user, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <h1>{user.username}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default graphql(getUsersQuery, createUserQuery) (App);
```

Comment: The `graphql` only takes a single query or mutation documents as a parameter. It's not clear why you're passing two different to the same HOC.

Comment: thanks for the response, how would i add the createUser mutation on the react side then ?

Comment: You'd utilize one hoc per query/mutation. You can use compose to combine them as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/#configname). In general though, it's much easier to drop the hoc in favor of the new hooks API.

Comment: ok that seemed to work. i can see the mutate function.  Apperciate it.